# Return a sub-list from a JSON list in Groovy active choices reactive reference parameter

Tags: arrays, json, list, jenkins, groovy

My active choices reactive reference parameter reads the following JSON file

```
{
"Name": "Tom",
"Age": "25",
"Subjects": ["English", "Physics", "Chemistry", "Biology", "Maths"]
}
```

The referenced parameters are `file`, `Nos` (previous active choices reactive parameter) which is a radio button with values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Now based on the values of `Nos`, I have to display the subjects. This is what I do:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def config = jsonSlurper.parse(new File(file))
return config.Subjects
```

With the above code, the output is,

```
 1. English
 2. Physics
 3. Chemistry
 4. Biology
 5. Maths
```

If I try to return `config.Subjects.take(Nos)` or `config.Subjects.subList(Nos)`, which I expect, if `Nos = 3` to be

```
1. English
2. Physics
3. Chemistry
```

But I see nothing. Then I tried,

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def config = jsonSlurper.parse(new File(file))
list = []
i = 0
config.Subjects.each {
while (i < Nos){
list.add "$it".toString()
i = i + 1
}
}
return list
```

But this time, I see `1. English` always, no matter which radio button I select. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is almost right. You should use `take` to slice the list. For example `take(2)` will return the first two elements. So instead of returning `config.Subjects`, try returning `(config.Subjects).take(Nos)`

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def config = jsonSlurper.parse(new File(file))
return (config.Subjects).take(Nos)
```

If Nos is a string, convert it into integer and return like this

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def config = jsonSlurper.parse(new File(file))
return (config.Subjects).take(Nos.toInteger())
```